# Listas ligadas - Adicionar ao final da lista

Tags: c

Boas.

Estou com o seguinte problema, fiz um pequeno programa para testes, onde crio uma lista com os dados de um cliente, nome e número, mas estou com problemas em adicionar ao final da lista. Se tentar adicionar ao início, não tenho qualquer problema, mas quando tento adicionar ao final surge o erro se "segmentation fault", no fundo adiciona o primeiro e depois para.
Deixo de seguida o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cliente
{
    char nome[40];
    int nr_cliente;
}cliente_t;

/*Criação do conceito de nó e respetivo método de remoção*/

typedef struct node
{
    cliente_t cliente;
    struct node* proximo; /*Apontador para o próximo nó*/
}node_c;

node_c* criar_no()
{
    node_c* node = NULL; 
    node = (node_c*)malloc(sizeof(node_c));
    node->proximo = NULL;
    return node;
}

void remover_no(node_c* node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        free(node);
    }
}

/*Criação do conceito de lista e respetivo método de insersão,remoção e pesquisa*/

typedef struct list
{
    node_c* head; /*Apontador para a cabeça da lista*/
}list_c;

list_c* criar_lista()
{
    list_c* list;
    list = (list_c*)malloc(sizeof(list_c));
    list->head = NULL;
    return (list);
}

list_c* remover_lista(list_c* list)
{
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        free(list);
        list = NULL;
    }
    return (list); /*retorna nulo*/
}

void insere_lista_topo(list_c* list, node_c* node)
{
    if (list->head != NULL)
    {
        node->proximo = list->head;
    }
    list->head = node;
}

void insere_lista_fim(list_c* list, node_c* node)
{
    node_c* node_aux = list->head;

    if (node_aux == NULL)
    {
        insere_lista_topo(list, node);
    }
    else
    {
        while (node_aux)
        {
            node_aux = node_aux->proximo;
        }
        node_aux = node;
        node->proximo = NULL;
    }
}


node_c* pesquisar_lista(list_c* list, int nr_cliente)
{
    node_c* node = list->head;
    int aux = 0;

    while (node)
    {
        if (aux == nr_cliente)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            aux++;
            node = node->proximo;
        }
    }
    return (node);
}

int main()
{
    node_c* node;
    list_c* list;
    int i;

    list = criar_lista();

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        node = criar_no();
        strcpy(node->cliente.nome, "Ze Manel");
        node->cliente.nr_cliente = i;
        node->proximo = NULL;
        insere_lista_fim(list, node);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        node = pesquisar_lista(list, i);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", node->cliente.nome);
        printf("Nr Cliente: %d\n", node->cliente.nr_cliente);
    }   
}
```

Comment: o ultimo node é NULL, fim da lista, percorrendo a lista  verifica se a ultima posição é **NULL** constatando que é verdadeira o proximo aponta para novo valor `proximo=NovoValor`.. ultima posição preenchida.

Comment: A lógica está errada. Só funciona para a lista vazia. Se a lista não está vazia precisa fazer com que o último aponte para o novo e o novo para NULL...

Answer (score 0):

A lógica está errada. Assim só funciona para a lista vazia, o caso trivial. Se a lista não está vazia precisa fazer com que o último elemento aponte para o novo e o novo para `NULL`...

```
void insere_lista_fim(list_c* list, node_c* node)
{
    node_c* node_aux = list->head;

    if (node_aux == NULL) { insere_lista_topo(list, node); }
    else
    {
        while (node_aux) { node_aux = node_aux->proximo; }
        node_aux      = node;
        node->proximo = NULL;
    }
}
```

- Não precisa de chaves num `while()` de 1 comando.
- não precisa do `else` numa condição definitiva. Simplesmente retorne
- talvez não devesse usar nomes tão grandes para um ponteiro auxiliar que só vai existir no loop

Estaria melhor com algo assim:

```
void insere_lista_fim(list_c* list, node_c* node)
{
    node_c* p = list->head;
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        insere_lista_topo(list, node);
        return;
    }
    while (p->proximo != NULL)  p = p->proximo;
    p->proximo      = node;
}
```

que funciona.

Em `main` isso também não está bom

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        node = criar_no();
        strcpy(node->cliente.nome, "Ze Manel");
        node->cliente.nr_cliente = i;
        node->proximo            = NULL;
        insere_lista_fim(list, node);
    }
```

- Nunca deixe uma variável com um nome ingênuo como `i` global em `main` ou qualquer função.
- Se está gerando dados use algo auditável ao máximo. Usar o mesmo nome porque?

Prefira algo como

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        node = criar_no();
        sprintf(node->cliente.nome, "Ze Mane %d", i);
        node->cliente.nr_cliente = i;
        node->proximo            = NULL;
        insere_lista_fim(list, node);
    }
```

E seu programa mostraria

```
Nome: Ze Mane 1
Nr Cliente: 1
Nome: Ze Mane 2
Nr Cliente: 2
Nome: Ze Mane 3
Nr Cliente: 3
Nome: Ze Mane 4
Nr Cliente: 4
Nome: Ze Mane 5
Nr Cliente: 5
```

Tem ainda muitos problemas no código.

Comment: Ah o SO-pt. Então minha resposta é inútil segundo ao menos 2 atentos leitores. Apesar de mostrar o que está errado. E explicar porque. E ter um exemplo em C de como poderia ser. E a saída do exemplo corrigido. Tenho mesmo que melhorar! :D